# Build a Query to get the informations from a specific user

Tags: sql

I'm building a Chat with three Tables.

Conversation, Conversation_reply and user

**Conversation Columns**

1. id
2. user_one
3. user_two

**Conversation_reply Columns**

1. id
2. user_id
3. conversation.id
4. reply

**User Columns**

1. id
2. username

I would like to build a list with the name from the users that are chating with a specific user.

Example, my ID is 711, and I am talking with three persons, I would like to get the username from those three persons.

I'm having some issues building this Query because the user_one and user_two are relative, the ID from the receiver sometimes can be inserted as user_one, or user_two. It depends on which user starts chatting first.

How can I build a Query to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your RDBMS you can check IF/ELSE, CASE/WHEN syntax.
Based on it you write statement:

```
SELECT if (user_one=711) user_two ELSE user_one
FROM conversation
where user_one=711 OR user_two=711
```

This is pseudocode, but idea should be clear.